# Открыть все изображения из выбранной папки

Tags: java, android, xml, recyclerview, imageview

У меня есть RecyclerView c элементами, каждый из которых содержит ImageView и TextView. Мне нужно заполнить эти ImageView изображениями из указанной директории, а TextView названиями этих соображений, соответственно. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, с чем именно  у Вас проблема. Вы не можете получить список фалов в директории? Или не знаете, как отобразить их с помощью RecyclerView?

Comment: Список файлов я получила, а именно следующим образм: ArrayList <File> imagesFromDirectory = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Objects.requireNonNull(folder.listFiles()))); теперь мне как - то нужно передать их в RecyclerView

Comment: Вам нужно написать адаптер, в который вы будете передавать ваш arraylist. Из полученные файлов должно быть возможно попасть полный путь и имя файла.
По пути можно загрузить картинку в Imageview,рекомендую использовать библиотеку piccasso для вывода изрбрашений. Стабильно работает, хорошо оптимизирован.